# How to change SBCL's current directory?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

It is *very* easy to change CLisp's current working directory:

```
>cat ~/.clisprc.lisp 
;;; The following lines added by ql:add-to-init-file:
#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp" (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
  (load quicklisp-init)))

(cd "/media/E/www/qachina/db/doc/money")
(load "money")
```

However, it seems there is no `cd` similar function in SBCL. How can this be done with SBCL?

Answer (score 18):

```
CL-USER> (sb-posix:chdir "/home/apugachev")
0
CL-USER> (sb-posix:getcwd)
"/home/apugachev"
CL-USER> (sb-posix:chdir "/tmp/")
0
CL-USER> (sb-posix:getcwd)
"/tmp"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change the directory that sbcl looks in when you call `(load ...)`.

Comment: @daveloyall I think that observation is worth its own top-level question.  It's puzzling behavior and I don't know the answer, either (I just work around it by using full path names all the time).

Comment: you could just do `(load (concatenate 'string (sb-posix:getcwd) "/" "my-foo.lisp"))`.  Pretty clumsy, I know, but a little less brittle.

Answer (score 15):

```
(setf *default-pathname-defaults* #P"/New/Absolute/Path/")
```

Answer (score 10):

Right now, better answer is: use `(uiop:chdir "some/path")`.

Or you can use this function to change directory temporarily:

`(uiop:call-with-current-directory "some/path"
    (lambda ()
       (do-the-job))`

Or this macro for more convenient way:

`(uiop:with-current-directory ("some/path")
   (do-the-job))`

Comment: Note: uiop package is available in most CL implementations directly. No need to load using asdf / quicklisp. The above code will run directly.

Comment: I'm using SBCL 2.0.0 in Windows and had to `(require "asdf")` to use uiop. It's the case that nothing had to be installed

Answer (score 8):

Had the same question. Turns out

```
(setf *default-pathname-defaults* (truename "./subdir"))
```

changes load path to subdir. If you don't want relative path, then

```
(setf *default-pathname-defaults* (truename "/absolute/path"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i use rlwrap to run SBCL and solves this problem

```
$"cat ~/bin/sb"
breakchars="(){}[],^%$#@\"\";:''|\\"

cd /media/E/www/qachina/db/doc/money/
exec rlwrap --remember -c -b "$breakchars"  -f "$HOME"/.sbcl_completions sbcl "$@"
```

then run `sb`.

Comment: Is it simpler than use of chdir?