# (sb-posix:chdir ) and (load)

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

Why is it that `sb-posix:chdir` doesn't seem to change `(truename ".")` nor `(load ...)`'s idea of cwd?

```
CL-USER> (sb-posix:getcwd)
"directory-B"
CL-USER> (sb-posix:chdir "directory-A")
0
CL-USER> (sb-posix:getcwd)
"directory-A"
CL-USER> (truename ".")
#P"directory-B"
CL-USER> (sb-posix:chdir "/tmp")
0
CL-USER> (truename ".")
#P"directory-B"
CL-USER> (load "some-file-under-dirA.asd")
; Evaluation aborted on #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR "~@<Couldn't load ~S: file does not exist.~@:>" {CE86631}>.
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: this may be related to [How to change SBCL's current directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7735677/1281433)

Comment: also see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/4Grsvch9p6Q

Comment: @Renzo I rephrased to make post look like a question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a little advertisment on the sb-posix [repository](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/1a858eddae05d91998592c453787ffeec36f579e/contrib/sb-posix/sb-posix.texinfo):

```
A few functions in sb-posix don't correspond directly to their C
counterparts.
```

So let's take a look on getcwd:

in C from [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html)

> The getcwd() function shall place an absolute pathname of the current
>   working directory in the array pointed to by buf, and return buf. The
>   pathname copied to the array shall contain no components that are
>   symbolic links. The size argument is the size in bytes of the
>   character array pointed to by the buf argument. If buf is a null
>   pointer, the behavior of getcwd() is unspecified.

and if we get the help of this function in slime or from the [repository](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/1a858eddae05d91998592c453787ffeec36f579e/contrib/sb-posix/interface.lisp) :

> "Returns the process's current working directory as a string."

The problem here is that SBCL current directoy is fixed in the special variable:

```
*default-pathname-defaults*
```

This is the reason why when you call truename and "." the SBCL shows you the current directory inside that variable which is not getting affected by the call sb-posix:chdir that really changes the sb-posix environment or the posix process. If you want to change also the SBCL directory (in slime you can use , cd and then type the new directory), you can go as follow but be careful because you are modifying a special variable that contains a pathname and for example it will not work well with slime (the command that I allready showed):

```
╭─anquegi@toshiba-debian  ~/learn/lisp/StackOverFlow/testDirs ‹ruby-2.2.1@laguna› 
╰─$ tree                                                                                                                                        148 ↵
.
├── dirA
└── dirB
    └── factorial.lisp

2 directories, 1 file
```

Then let's got to slime

```
; SLIME 2015-06-01
CL-USER> (sb-posix:getcwd)
"/home/anquegi/learn/lisp/StackOverFlow/testDirs"
CL-USER> *default-pathname-defaults*
#P"/home/anquegi/learn/lisp/StackOverFlow/testDirs/"
CL-USER> (sb-posix:chdir "dirB")
0
CL-USER> (sb-posix:getcwd)
"/home/anquegi/learn/lisp/StackOverFlow/testDirs/dirB"
CL-USER> *default-pathname-defaults*
#P"/home/anquegi/learn/lisp/StackOverFlow/testDirs/"
CL-USER> (setf *default-pathname-defaults* (sb-ext:native-pathname (format nil "~A~A" (sb-posix:getcwd) "/"))) 
#P"/home/anquegi/learn/lisp/StackOverFlow/testDirs/dirB/"
CL-USER> (load "factorial")
T
CL-USER> (factorial 3)
6
```

Please take care of transforming the string in a pathname and add the "/", I'm not sure why SBCL took this way of working. separating sb-posix from sbcl paths